# How to compute the unique disintegration w.r.t. the first coordinate?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, optimal-transportation

Set $\pi=\frac{1}{4}(\delta_{(1,0)}++\delta_{(1,3)}+\delta_{(1,1)}+\delta_{(2,2)})$. Suppose that $\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)$.

How to get the disintegration of $\pi$ with respect to $\mu$?

Comment: The question has become incomprehensible after the edit.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker The question is just simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By disintegration is meant that $\pi$ can by broken down as
$$
\pi(dx,dy) =\mu(dx)\pi_{x}(dy),
$$
with $\pi_x$ a Borel measurable family of sub-probability measures on $X$.

In your example:
$\pi_{x_1}={1\over 2}(\delta_{0}+\delta_{1})$ if $x_1=1$; $=\delta_{2}$ if $x_1=2$; and $=0$ otherwise.

Then   you have $W_1(\pi_{x_1},\nu) = 1/2$ if $x_1=1$, and $W_1(\pi_{x_1},\nu)=1$ if $x_1=2$.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Suppose $\pi$ is the joint distribution of random variables $Y$ and $Z$. (The marginal distribution of $Y$ is therefore $\mu$.) Using the definition of conditional expectation you have
$$
\eqalign{
E[E[f(Z)\mid Y] g(Y)]]=
&=E[f(Z)g(Y)] =\int_{X\times X} g(y)f(z)\pi(dy,dz)\cr
&=\int_Xg(y)\mu(dy)\left[\int_X f(z) \pi_y(dz)\right]\cr
&=\int_X g(y)h(y)\mu(dy)\cr
&=E[g(Y)h(Y)],
}
$$
where
$$
h(y):=\int_Xf(z)\pi_y(dz).
$$
Thus, the random variable $h(Y)$ has the properties required of $E[f(Z)\mid Y]$, so we must have $E[f(Z)\mid Y]=\int_X f(z)\,\pi_Y(dz)$, a.s., for each bounded measurable $f$. This amounts to saying that $(\omega, B)\mapsto\pi_{Y(\omega)}(B)$ is a regular conditional distribution for $Z$ given $Y$.

**2.** If $\pi$ were absolutely continuous with respect to the product measure $\mu\otimes\nu$, say
$$
\pi(dy,dz)=\rho(y,z)\mu(dy)\nu(dz),
$$
then clearly
$$
\pi_y(dz) = \rho(y,z)\,\nu(dz).
$$
Notice that because $\mu$ is the distribution of $Y$, you have $\int_X\rho(y,z)\nu(dz)=1$ for $\mu$-a.e. $y$.

**3.** To check that $W_1(\pi_{x_1},\nu)=1/2$ one can guess at a most efficient way to transport the mass of $\pi_{x_1}$ to that of $\nu$ (namely, take $1/6$ from $\pi_{x_1}$ at $0$ and at $1$ and move the combined weight to $2$ to obtain $\nu$. This gives a transport cost of $(1/6)\cdot 1+(1/6)\cdot 2 = 1/2$.